# Can ${n \choose 2}$ points be covered by lines determined by $n$ points?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $S=\{(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_{n \choose 2},b_{n \choose 2})\}$ be ${n \choose 2}$ points on the plane. Does there exist $n$ points, such that the lines determined by the $n$ points cover all the points in $S$?

One can formulate this as an algebra problem.

We consider variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n$, so $(x_i,y_i)$ would be the position of the $i$th point.

To detect if any line determined by the points covers $(a_k,b_k)\in S$, it requires the following polynomial

$$ P_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n) = \prod_{i\neq j} \left|\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_i & y_i \\ 1 & x_j & y_j \\ 1 & a_k & b_k \\ \end{pmatrix} \right| = 0$$.

Then one can see there is a solution iff there is a 0 for the following polynomial. it's detecting if there is a zero for the following polynomial.

$$ P = \sum_{i=1}^{{n\choose 2}} P_k^2$$. $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

However, there are always degenerate solutions because there can be two points $(x_i,y_i)=(x_j,y_j)$.

So we need that $(x_i,y_i)\neq (x_j,y_j)$ for all $j\neq i$. This can be encoded as another polynomial. $Q_{i,j}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n) = (x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2$. $Q = \prod_{i\neq j} Q_{i,j}$.

Thus now we want to know if the polynomial $P+Q$ has any $0$s.

Then I'm stuck. I think there must be some algebra tool that I don't know of. One thing comes to mind is there seems to be only $n$ degrees of freedom but we might need ${n \choose 2}$ degrees of freedom, but I don't see a way to formulate this.

Comment: It seems like you have $2n$ degrees of freedom for placing the $n$ source points, and then an additional ${n}\choose{2}$ degrees of freedom for selecting a point on each line; while you have $2{{n}\choose{2}}$ degrees of freedom for placing the target points.  So when ${{n}\choose{2}} = n(n-1)/2 > 2n$ (i.e., $n>5$) you won't generically have a way to do it.